# If I want to learn mathematical optimization where should I start?

Tags: reference-request, optimization

I'm working in the area of transportation engineering, to be specific, mostly involved in management. I read some papers in Transportation research part x, and something like that, and noticed that I need to learn mathematics and computer science,I've learned some calculus and I'm good at C++ and matlab, so I want to start my mathematical journey.
I want to know where to start, please offer me some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend "Mathematical Modeling" by Mark M. Meerschaert.

Comment: A bit of context (date? publisher?) about this work (book? paper?) and how it addresses the learning of mathematical optimization would be welcome.